# Types and nature of singularities of f(z)=1/z ln(1-z)

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, singularity-theory

Consider the complex function f(z) = (1/z)×ln(1-z) ,
It seems like having a removable singularity (because,while comparing with corresponding real function,the limit exists.)
The function has a branch point at z=1.
Apart from my above findings, what more singularities are there?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

If $\ln z$ is the principal branch of logarithm then you have to remove the entire $[1,\infty)$ to get an analytic function. The function is not even continuous at points of this interval. Once you remove this part of the real axis you get an analytic function; the singularity at $0$ is actually removable.